# Dimensioning plugin not responding

Tags: qgis-plugins, dimensions

Trying to create a dim line on QGIS 3.16, Windows 10.
The Dimensioning plugin seems to be installed, and even created one dim line, but stopped responding (I updated and re-installed it, it didn't help).
the dimlinear in QAD plugin doesn't work at all (see picture below).
[image: command line of QAD plugin]

Answer (score 0):

what's the value of dimstyle variable ?
You can run dimstyle command to verify all dim styles.
Each dim style is composed by 3 layer.